# Python - Initialzing tkinter inside class,and what happens when need another gui in another class?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a 'read from  csv file' class. This class should read a csv file and return result as a list.So far- quite simple even for a newbie as me.

BUT- I need something a bit more complexed:

1) If filename is not given ( as an argument to class) - a file selection dialog box pops up to select one.

2) Optional: show file's content in a GUI, using a `CSVGui` class (using method `self.out_in_gui`).

Since `ReadCSV` is not GUI based class, GUI is initialized only in need to launch a `askopenfilename`. A use of `widtdraw()` is made in order not to show additinal blank GUI.

**The probelm** is: When I try to read a file, without spcifing one, a file selection dialog pops up, PLUS calling method `self.out_in_gui` to execute `CSVGui` class - file contents does not show in GUI (Entries left empty).

**TRIES**:when I specify as a parameter, the file to be loaded, everything runs OK. My guess- it has something to do with using the GUI in `ReadFile` to load file selection GUI.

Thanks
J

```
import csv
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename


class ReadFile:
    """This class reads CSV w/out header line, and returen it as a list"""

    def __init__(self, fname='', path='', **kwargs):
        if fname == '' and path == '':
            tk.Tk().withdraw()
            self.filename = askopenfilename(title='Select CSV file', filetypes=[('CommaSeperatedFile', '*.csv')])
        else:
            if path != '':
                self.filename = path + '/' + fname
            else:
                self.filename = fname
        self.file_content = []
        self.read_file(kwargs)
        self.out_in_gui()

    def read_file(self, kwargs):
        with open(self.filename, newline='', **kwargs) as csvfile:
            file_obj = csv.reader(csvfile)
            for i in file_obj:
                self.file_content.append(i)
            print("file %s was read successfully, containing %d lines" % (self.filename, len(self.file_content)))

    def out_in_gui(self):
        print("send data to CSVGui")
        CSVGui(self, data=self.file_content)

    def file_contents(self):
        return self.file_content


class CSVGui(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, data=[]):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        # csvroot = tk.Tk()
        fname = 'No file loaded'
        # if data is not None and master is not None:
        #     fname = self.master.filename
        # csvroot.title("CSVGui - " + fname)
        self.frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text='Data set', padding=10)
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.widgets_frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.widgets_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.m, self.row_vars = [], []
        self.exec_gui(data)
        print(data)
        # self.read_from_gui()
        # csvroot.mainloop()

    def exec_gui(self, data):
        # populted and create GUI with data
        for r in range(len(data)):
            self.m = []
            self.ent = ''
            for col in range(len(max(data))):
                self.m.append(tk.StringVar())
                self.ent = ttk.Entry(self.frame, textvariable=self.m[-1], state=tk.NORMAL)
                self.ent.grid(row=r, column=col)
                try:
                    self.m[-1].set(data[r][col])
                    print("IN")
                except IndexError:
                    self.m[-1].set('')
                    print("OUT")
            # create structured vector of var for use in save mode
            self.row_vars.append(self.m)

        self.create_widgets()
        print("CSVGui - Created")

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.save_button = ttk.Button(self.widgets_frame, text='Save', command=self.save2file)
        self.save_button.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.exit_button = ttk.Button(self.widgets_frame, text='Exit')  # , command=print('Exit'))
        self.exit_button.grid(row=0, column=1)
        tk.Spinbox(self.widgets_frame, width=5, from_=0, to=20).grid()

    def read_from_gui(self):
        data_list = []
        for r, rows in enumerate(self.row_vars):
            c_data = []
            for c, cols in enumerate(rows):
                if cols.get() != '':
                    c_data.append(cols.get())
            data_list.append(c_data)

        return data_list

    def save2file(self):
        WriteFile('w', self.master.filename, data=self.read_from_gui())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it doesn't work for me because problem is `master`

In `ReadFile` you run `CSVGui(self, ...)` and `self` means `ReadFile`. In `CSVGui` you assign this `ReadFile` to `master` and use in `ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)` - but `master` has to be any `tkinter's` widget, not `ReadFile`.

I made changes in two places

First: in `ReadFile` I create `Tk()` window and after `askopenfilename` I destroy it. This way if I run `ReadFile()` or `ReadFile(filename.csv)` I always will run `CSVGui` without `master` in computer memory.

```
   if fname == '' and path == '':
        master = tk.Tk()
        master.withdraw()
        self.filename = askopenfilename(title='Select CSV file', filetypes=[('CommaSeperatedFile', '*.csv')])
        master.destroy()
```

Second: `CSVGui` doesn't need `master` as second argument because I create it inside `CSVGui`

```
class CSVGui(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, data=[]):
        master = tk.Tk()
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
```

It also need `self.pack()` to put `class CSVGui(ttk.Frame)` inside this master, and `master.mainloop()` to keep it open.

---

```
import csv
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename


class ReadFile:
    """This class reads CSV w/out header line, and returen it as a list"""

    def __init__(self, fname='', path='', **kwargs):
        if fname == '' and path == '': # <--- changes
            master = tk.Tk()
            master.withdraw()
            self.filename = askopenfilename(title='Select CSV file', filetypes=[('CommaSeperatedFile', '*.csv')])
            master.destroy()
        else:
            if path != '':
                self.filename = path + '/' + fname
            else:
                self.filename = fname
        self.file_content = []
        self.read_file(kwargs)
        self.out_in_gui()

    def read_file(self, kwargs):
        with open(self.filename, newline='', **kwargs) as csvfile:
            file_obj = csv.reader(csvfile)
            for i in file_obj:
                self.file_content.append(i)
            print("file %s was read successfully, containing %d lines" % (self.filename, len(self.file_content)))

    def out_in_gui(self):
        print("send data to CSVGui")
        CSVGui(self.filename, data=self.file_content) # <--- changes

    def file_contents(self):
        return self.file_content


class CSVGui(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, filename, data=[]): # <--- changes
        self.filename = filename # <--- changes

        master = tk.Tk() # <--- changes
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid() # <--- changes (updated. was `pack` before)

        # csvroot = tk.Tk()
        fname = 'No file loaded'
        # if data is not None and master is not None:
        #     fname = self.master.filename
        # csvroot.title("CSVGui - " + fname)
        self.frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text='Data set', padding=10)
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.widgets_frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.widgets_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.m, self.row_vars = [], []
        self.exec_gui(data)
        print(data)
        # self.read_from_gui()
        # csvroot.mainloop()
        master.mainloop() # <--- changes

    def exec_gui(self, data):
        # populted and create GUI with data
        for r in range(len(data)):
            self.m = []
            self.ent = ''
            for col in range(len(max(data))):
                self.m.append(tk.StringVar())
                self.ent = ttk.Entry(self.frame, textvariable=self.m[-1], state=tk.NORMAL)
                self.ent.grid(row=r, column=col)
                try:
                    self.m[-1].set(data[r][col])
                    print("IN")
                except IndexError:
                    self.m[-1].set('')
                    print("OUT")
            # create structured vector of var for use in save mode
            self.row_vars.append(self.m)

        self.create_widgets()
        print("CSVGui - Created")

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.save_button = ttk.Button(self.widgets_frame, text='Save', command=self.save2file)
        self.save_button.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.exit_button = ttk.Button(self.widgets_frame, text='Exit')  # , command=print('Exit'))
        self.exit_button.grid(row=0, column=1)
        tk.Spinbox(self.widgets_frame, width=5, from_=0, to=20).grid()

    def read_from_gui(self):
        data_list = []
        for r, rows in enumerate(self.row_vars):
            c_data = []
            for c, cols in enumerate(rows):
                if cols.get() != '':
                    c_data.append(cols.get())
            data_list.append(c_data)

        return data_list

    def save2file(self):
        WriteFile('w', self.filename, data=self.read_from_gui()) # <--- changed

ReadFile()
```

---

EDIT: I added `filename` to `CSVGui(self.filename, data=self.file_content)`

Comment: thank you for such a full asnwer. since I want to pass filename to csv ( as I did in my code ), how can it be done with your s?

Comment: you can add filename as argument `def __init__(self, filename, data=[]):` and save it in `self.filename`. And later use `self.filename`. BTW: I added it in answer.

Comment: coding `self.pack` will cause problem since entire code contains `grid` method

Comment: @guy you are right, it wasn't main problem in question so I didn't see it.